# how to plot this function in R

Tags: r, plot

I know that looks like a silly question but how can I plot this function,

|x|+|y|=z

in 2D by R. I know that is a kind of contour plot but don't know how to manage that.

Comment: I think maple or sage will be more appropriate than R for question like this ?

Comment: `x, y, z` looks like 3D to me.

Comment: yes that us 3D. what I am looking for is the projection of 3d on 2d space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `contour` and try this small example

```
X=seq(-1, 1, length.out=10)
Y=seq(-1, 1, length.out=10)
Z=outer(X, Y, FUN= function(x,y) abs(x)+abs(y))
contour(x=X, y=Y, z=Z)
```